# Not getting push notification in iPhone

Tags: iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have used the following code for push notification and it also gives me message Connected to APNS Message successfully 
delivered.
my Iphone uid is also correct, but still I don't get and notification in iPhone. I thought there is an error in Pem file, but when I used parse sever I received the notification already. I could not find what the problem can anyone help me.

```
    <?php

// Put your device token here (without spaces):
$deviceToken = '8945fccefc3a11ea07e208238091595a688d2fa0';

// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'compass';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'My first push notification!';

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default'
    );

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: maybe server where you upload this php file, doesn't have the port 2195 open.

Comment: i uploaded on two server , and try on localhost also

Comment: from localhost not work? from your terminal?

Comment: i did from live also i receive a message delivered  but no notification received .